Which .Net framework supports Azure Key vault?
I have a few web applications developed in .Net framework 4 and 4.5. My team says, with the application developed using .Net framework 4 and 4.5, it can't fetch the Keys and Secrets from the Azure Key vault.
My question is, from what version of .Net framework the Azure Key Vault is supported?

The SKD needs .Net 4.6.1 as a minimum, see the nuget. I suppose upgrading your apps from 4.5 to 4.6.1 isn't that much of a big deal.

Do you mean the client library/package or Key Vault itself?

.. or you use the REST Api, see the docs. Then it doesn't matter what framework version your app uses.

... eg. using the REST API directly (not using a client library) is independent of the client platform/tech-stack. You should, however, be focusing on upgrad8ing from end of life versions of .NET (Framework and Core).

Thanks @Peter Bons for the comments
The document shared by Peter Bons has a clear list of current versions which supports Key Vault.

You can see the option to add Key Vault from Connected Services in .NET Framework 4 and 4.5 versions as well without any default code.



Whereas you can see the default code/configuration related to Key Vault is available from .NET 4.7.1 Version.

  <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="[VaultName]" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>


what version of .Net framework the Azure Key Vault is supported ?


Even though the option is available in older versions, the framework may not support all the libraries required to retrieve the keys.

If you want full support, it is advised to upgrade your version to latest as suggested by Peter Bons.


Also refer this Release History of Key Vault SDK.
